# Difficulty in creating custom login page in android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

hi i am making an app where i'm creating a login page and i have code for that as well now my problem is my design is messed up
Here is what i have got so far
[image: My current Output]
and here is my [image: expected output]
I dont know how i can make it better according to my expected result so please if someone can guide me here..
Thank you.

[image: facebook icon][image: google icon]
my xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.ct.listrtrial.activities.LoginActivity">

    <com.ct.listrtrial.Custom.CustomTextViewMedium
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Login"
        android:textColor="@color/White"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_corner_image"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@color/White">
            <com.ct.listrtrial.Custom.CustomEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:hint="Email id"

                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/message"/>
            <com.ct.listrtrial.Custom.CustomEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/lock"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:hint="Password"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <com.ct.listrtrial.Custom.CustomTextViewMedium
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:text="Forgot Password?"
        android:textColor="@color/White"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <com.ct.listrtrial.widget.CustomButton
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ripple_button_effect"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text="Login"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <com.ct.listrtrial.Custom.CustomTextViewMedium
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="OR CONNECT WITH"
        android:textColor="@color/White"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/facebook"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/facebook"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
            <com.ct.listrtrial.Custom.CustomImageView
                android:id="@+id/google"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/facebook"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/google_plus"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:background="@drawable/login_page_curve"/>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true">
        <com.ct.listrtrial.Custom.CustomTextViewMedium
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:text="Or"/>
            <com.ct.listrtrial.Custom.CustomTextViewBold
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Register"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

and my custom curve for bottom imageview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"/>
    </item>
    <item
        android:bottom="-580dp"
        android:left="-150dp"
        android:right="-150dp"
        android:top="0dp">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/White" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#00ddff"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context="com.ct.listrtrial.activities.LoginActivity">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:text="Login"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="35sp" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorAccent"
            app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
            app:cardElevation="5dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_message"
                    android:hint="Email id"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:textColor="#000" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_search"
                    android:hint="Password"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:textColor="#000" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:text="Forgot Password?"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFf"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:text="Login"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:text="OR CONNECT WITH"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="15sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/facebook"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/fb" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/google"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/facebook"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/gmail" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/test" />


            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
                    android:text="Or"
                    android:textColor="#d90a0a"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/text"
                    android:text="Register"
                    android:textColor="#e61313"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

            </RelativeLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Nilesh thanks for the answer but my cardview corner radius is not showing.

Comment: @john which cardview

Comment: @john remove `android:background="#FFFFFF"` from your Linearlayout try updated answer

Comment: if remove color from linear layout then i'm not able to give color to cardview

Comment: @john set background color in cardview using `app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorAccent"` try updated answer

Comment: thanks and one more thing how can i have only one line between two editext as in the image @Nilesh

Comment: Thanks @Nilesh it works just wanted to know about the spacing between icon and text.

Comment: @john use **`android:drawablePadding="10dp"`**

Comment: my facebook and google login icons are still in a bad shape what should i do

Comment: use `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` in imageview icon

Comment: i gave wrap content to both the images still it is not looking same as this https://imgur.com/a/CMJ8PKd

Comment: @john share image of facebook and gmail with question

Comment: still having the same issue.

Comment: @john try to change icon size using photoshop

Comment: @john download icon from here as per your requirement https://www.flaticon.com/packs/android-app

Comment: i wanted to know how i can set color to facebook and google icon because when i add image it takes the background color and i'm using custom round imageview so if i give background color to imageview it shows white on corners.

Comment: @john didn't get u

Comment: i mean when i add google and facebook icons they take the layouts background color so when i set background color to imageview the icons color change to white but as i'm using custom surved imageview white color is also visible in the corners of imageview

Comment: @john `google and facebook icons they take the layouts background color` because your ison color is transaparant you need to change it using photoshop or doenload new icon

Comment: icons color are actually white which i downloaded from flaticon now